# jqplot label is not shown

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot. The labels are getting hided when the value is near to tick. Here the label value is $9.25 and it is near to $10 and so the label is not displayed. How to fix this issue ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

```
var plot = //draw plot here
plot.axes.yaxis.max += (plot.axes.yaxis.tickInterval / 2);
plot.replot();
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue on the xaxis. Since i couldn't get the last pointer label to render, I added another ticker without displaying the ticker label. That gave the graph more space to print the pointer label.